# Why hibernate won't allow to generate table name dynamically in a native query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having an entity `QuestionStats` for which I have implemented a dao interface using Spring-data-jpa

```
public interface QuestionStatsDao extends JpaRepository<QuestionStats, QuestionStatsId>{

    @Query(value = "SELECT AVG(vote) FROM :entity WHERE question_id = :questionId", nativeQuery = true)
    Double getVotesAverage(@Param("entity") String entity, @Param("questionId") Integer questionId);

}
```

Test

```
@Test
    public void getQuestionStats() {
        Question question = questionDao.findById(1).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException() );
        System.out.println("rating: " + questionStatsDao.getVotesAverage(QuestionStats.class.getAnnotation(Table.class).name(),1));

        assertNotNull(question);
    }
```

Notice I am passing the table dynamically to the jpa interface using `QuestionStats.class.getAnnotation(Table.class).name()`. And even this is bringing up the correct table name as string. The problem here is with hibernate which is not allowing me to create table name dynamically in SQL and giving SQLGrammer exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:242)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.getVotesAverage(Unknown Source)
  at test.ofloy.persistence.QuestionDaoTest.getQuestionStats(QuestionDaoTest.java:64)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2168)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
  at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2200)
  at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016)
  at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152)
  at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
  at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1463)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:214)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
  at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
  ... 41 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''question_stats' WHERE question_id = 1' at line 1
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
  ... 69 more
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: the problem is that `@Param("entity") String entity` gets converted to `'question_stats'` note the '

Comment: Ohh, this is the problem with String parameter which get enclosed by single quotes.

Comment: ...because the whole idea of using `@Query` is to have the query precompiled. If you want dynamic queries, use the Criteria API